# Angular JS: How do you refresh smart table from putside to show default sorting

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using smart table for Grid. My Grid has one column as default sorting. After user sort on other columns will click on a Reset button to refresh the grid sorted by default column as well as indicator also reset back to default column?

```
  <table st-table="displayedPatients" st-safe-src="patients" class="table table-condensed ">
   <thead>
      <tr>          
        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="patientLastname" >Last Name</th>
        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="patientFirstname" >First Name</th>

        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="patientHomePhone">Telephone</th>
        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="rxNumber">Rx Number</th>
        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="din">DIN</th>

        <th class="st-sort-descent" st-sort="txFileDate" st-sort-default="reverse">Last Fill Date</th>



      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="patient in displayedPatients" >
        <td>{{patient.patientLastname}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.patientFirstname}}</td>           
        <td>{{patient.patientHomePhone}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.rxNumber}}</td>    
        <td>{{patient.din}}</td>

        <td>{{patient.txFileDate |  date:'dd-MMM-yy' }}</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

How do you write button action to reset to default?